# Not able to close the browser using NightwatchJS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to open my url using Nightwatch and I wan't able to close the browser afterwards.

I tried using [timeouts](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/timeouts.html), as well as `browser.end()`, or `browser.closeWindow()`. None of them seem to be working for my url.

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test mywrkouts' : function (browser) {
    browser.url('https://www.mywrkouts.com/workouts/search')
    browser.timeouts('script', 10000, function(result) {
    browser.end();
      console.log("Test result"+result);
    });
    //browser.closeWindow();
  }
};
```

It opens the page, but doesn't close the browser. I am using Chrome browser with `chromedriver`. I am expecting to close the window, but it doesn't work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is it because you have browser.closeWindow(); commented out?

Comment: I tried with both commenting and without commenting it and none of them works for me. Can you please try the same code snippet in your IDE if possible and help me out? TIA.

Comment: @KrishnaA what are you trying to achieve? Not what is happening, what is the flow you want to test. I cannot help you unless you are more specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LE:** Like I extensibly described below, ***you don't need to explicitly close the browser at the end of the test*** (via `browser.end()`) as the Nightwatch test-runner does that for you at the end of each feature-file.

But, if you need to do some *teardown operations* and then explicitly close the session, do it in an `after` (or `afterEach`) hook. Try the following snippet:

```
module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    browser.maximizeWindow();
  },

  'My Wrkouts Test': (browser) => {

    browser.url('https://www.mywrkouts.com/');
    // Check if the website logo is visible:
    browser.expect.element('#barbell-homepage-top-image-desktop img.app-bar-desktop-logo').to.be.visible;
    // Check the articles heading text:
    browser.expect.element('h3.blog-carousel-title.primary-blue-text.center').text.to.contain('Foundational Education Series');
  },

  after(browser, done) {
    browser.end(() => {
      console.info('*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*');
      console.info('*-- Clossing session... Good bye! --*');
      console.info('*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*');
      done();
    });
  }
};
```

---

Anyways, I feel you are confusing the way NightwatchJS/WebdriverIO/Protractor (*or any other Webdriver-based test solution*) is handling a `browser` session.

First off, you need not worry about closing the **active session**. Nightwatch does it for you at the end of each **test feature-file**. Thus, running a suit of let's say three test suites (`login.js`, `register.js`, `forgot_password.js`) will sequentially spawn & close three different `browser` sessions.

Also, [browser.closeWindow()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#closeWindow) is only used for closing a `window` instance (*taking into account that you have multiple windows associated with the same `browser` session*). It won't close your main `window`, unless you have switched to another `window` instance (*which was previously opened during your test run*).

If you use [browser.end()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/end.html) in the middle of your test, then you basically kill the active session, nullifying the following logic from your feature-file:

```
INFO Request: DELETE /wd/hub/session/4a4bb4cb1b38409ee466b0fc8af78101
 - data:
 - headers:  {"Content-Length":0,"Authorization":"Basic Z29wcm86YmM3MDk2MGYtZGE0Yy00OGUyLTk5MGMtMzA5MmNmZGJhZTMz"}
INFO Response 200 DELETE /wd/hub/session/4a4bb4cb1b38409ee466b0fc8af78101 (56ms) { sessionId: '4a4bb4cb1b38409ee466b0fc8af78101',
  status: 0,
  value: null }
LOG     → Completed command end (57 ms)
```

Everything after will look like this:

```
INFO Response 404 POST /wd/hub/session/null/elements (11ms) { sessionId: 'null',
  value:
   { error: 'invalid session id',
     message: 'No active session with ID null',
     stacktrace: '' },
  status: 6 }
```

> **!Note:** There is no support for doing what you are trying to do, nor is it a common use-case, thus the lack of support for it across
>   all of these testing solutions.

*They say a picture is worth 1000 words*, so let's me simply put it this way... what you are trying to do is synonymous with the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @iamdanchiv for the detailed explanation. Here is my flow which I'm trying to achieve.

Steps:
1. Open the url "https://www.mywrkouts.com/"
2. Just close the browser.

I tried with below code

Comment: module.exports = {
  tags: ['myTest'],
  before : function (browser) {
    browser.resizeWindow(1400, 800);
  },
  'Test #1' : function (browser) {
    return browser
      .url('https://www.mywrkouts.com/')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000); 
  },
  after : function (browser) {
    browser.end();
  }
}

Comment: @KrishnaA I've updated the answer. Try it and tell me if it works. If all's well, consider closing the question. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. followed above code, facing following issues.

Comment: @imadanchiv 
1. browser.maximizeWindow() is not maximizing the window in chrome browser.
2. As an alternate to #1 used browser.resizeWindow(1400,800) but the test is not passing consistently as it fails to find expected element.

 ✖ mywrkoutslogin
 – My Wrkouts Test (1m 23s)
   Expected element <#barbell-homepage-top-image-desktop img.app-bar-desktop-logo> to be visible - element was not found - expected "visible" but got: "not found"

Comment: It looks like you're page isn't loaded at the `expect` step. Is your page loading? You should try to use a `browser.pause(5000)` (_sleep for 5 seconds_) after the `.url()` step and see if it passes. If so, look into `waitUntil` and use that. But oddly enough it should pass (_runs flawlessly on my end_), so the issue is somewhere in your setup.

Comment: I've updated the code, it wouldn't ever execute the `maximizeWindow( )`, cause I forgot the switch (`if isMobile`) which didn't have any logic for your setup. Anyways, cut the `before` hook altogether, that was only for example.

Comment: It's not even pausing the browser. I am using following configurations.

1. Chrome Browser Version :  Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. Selenium Stand alone Jar: 3.12.0
3. Operating system : Mac

Could you please let me know which version of chrome driver and stand alone jar your using and is working fine?

Comment: **Chromedriver version:** 72.0.3626.81 | **Selenium version:** 3.13.0 | **Nightwatch version:** 0.9.21. **Env:** MacOS, Mojave. The example is working perfectly.

Comment: Issue was with my Chromedriver. Upgraded to latest driver and it started working without any issues.Thanks a lot @iamdanchiv for the complete help.

Comment: Could you please suggest me any git repo or any links to follow a basic framework model for Nightwatch. I started exploring nightwatch after working on Selenium Webdriver with testng framework. It would be great if you can suggest me any github links to follow a simple framework model.

Comment: When I first started, [Learn Nightwatch](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch) was the **go-to** repo for learning NightwatchJS. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm looking for something that has proper structure for maintaining actions, locators, page components, tests, data providers and any other utilities.