# Nightwatch.js function not 'closing'

Tags: javascript, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to perform a function at the beginning of my test, then the rest of the test should be executed.

This is my **custom-command** (named `internalAdviceLinksHtml`):

```
var solr = require('solr-client')

exports.command = function() {
  this
  var client = solr.createClient('solr.dev.bauerhosting.com', 8080, 'cms', '/www.parkers.co.uk');
  var globalSettingsQuery = client.createQuery()
      .q({TypeName:'Bauer.Parkers.GlobalSettings'})
      .start(0)
      .rows(10);  

  client.search(globalSettingsQuery,function(err,obj) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {      
      var myresult = (obj.response.docs[0].s_InternalAdviceLinksHtml);

      console.log(myresult.length);
      if (myresult.length === 0) {
        console.log('content block not configured');
      } else {    
        console.log('content block configured');
      }
    }
  });        
  return this;
};
```

**Test-file** (*script*):

```
module.exports = {
  'set up the solr query': function (browser) {
    browser
      .solr_query.global_settings.internalAdviceLinksHtml();
  },

  'links above footer on advice landing page displayed': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carAdvice)
      .assert.elementPresent('section.seo-internal-links')
  },

  'closing the browser': function (browser)  {
    browser
      .browserEnd();
  },  
};
```

The function works correctly (i.e. if `myresult` length is 0 then ***"content block is not configured"*** is displayed, etc), but the following test (*"links above footer on advice landing page displayed"*) is never invoked.

It seems like the execution stops after the **custom-command**. I'm sure this will be something quite obvious to someone, but I just can't seem to see what it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work Darren? Tried the below approaches?

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv , many thanks for you reply to this, and apologies for the lateness of the reply.  I implemented the changes to the command and test scripts as per you suggestions, but unfortunately this is still not working as the test still 'hangs'.  So, I'm going to try the hooks suggestion, in the hope that this resolves the issue.  I'll post my outcome on here after I've read up on the nightwatch.js literature regarding hooks.

Comment: Just a quick update on this.  The browser launches, but it doesn't navigate to the defined URL, it just 'hangs' with an open, but blank browser window.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much obvious Darren since the `internalAdviceLinksHtml` command never resolves so the test-runner hangs. (_the `.url( )` command is never executed_). What Nightwatch version are you running?! I'd try to run the test without the `internalAdviceLinksHtml()` step & validate if that works (_use a working URL, just comment that step & make the test pass_). Then it's clear that something is left hanging in the `solr` lib. You might want to check what those commands are returning, if anything... they might break the promise chain.

Comment: @iamdanchiv 
Ok, so I added the code that is in my custom command into my actual test script, and it passed (i.e. the entire test script ran, and completed). So the problem only seems to occur when I'm referencing my command file. I've never experienced that issue before, and seems very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your `internalAdviceLinksHtml` custom-command, everything looks good from my point of view (*I presume that lonely `this` was a typo*).

Your hunch is correct, it seems that the Nightwatch test-runner fails to go to the next test, which is probably due to some promise not being resolved upstream (`client.search` function from `internalAdviceLinksHtml`).

I would recommend doing a `return this` immediately after outputting to console (***content block not configured***,  or ***content block configured***) and see if that fixes the problem:

```
  client.search(globalSettingsQuery,function(err,obj) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {      
      var myresult = (obj.response.docs[0].s_InternalAdviceLinksHtml);

      console.log(myresult.length);
      if (myresult.length === 0) {
        console.log('content block not configured');
      } else {    
        console.log('content block configured');
      }
    }
    return this
  });
```

---

Also, a few extra pointers:

- make use of the Nightwatch [test-hooks](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/using-nightwatch/test-hooks.md) to make your tests easier to read/maintain & create a separation of concern (***setup*** => `before`/`beforeEach` hooks | ***teardown*** (e.g: `browser.end()`) => `after`/`afterEach` hooks);
- you need not do an explicit `browser.end()` at the end of your test case. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54536249/1458144) answer for more information on the matter.

Your test-file would become:

```
module.exports = {
  // > do your setup here <
  before(browser) {
    browser
      .solr_query.global_settings.internalAdviceLinksHtml();
  },

  'links above footer on advice landing page displayed': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carAdvice)
      .assert.elementPresent('section.seo-internal-links');
  },
  // > do your cleanup here <
  after(browser)  {
    browser
      .browserEnd();
  },  
};
```